# How to properly switch tabs in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap, I am trying to learn how to switch tabs. This is what I got so far

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!--
        <input id="test"/>
        <input id="test2"/>
        -->

        <div id="myTabs" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Pal</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div id="myTabPanes" class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">qqq</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="about" style="display:none;">ggg</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="contact" style="display:none;">jjj</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mvc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    $('#myTabs li').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#myTabPanes > div:visible").hide();
        $($(this).find("a").attr("href")).show();
    });
    $('#myTabs a.brand').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#myTabs .nav li').eq(0).click();
    });
```

The problem is I am sorta hacking bootstrap to make tabs with in my JS code. I don't think this is the right way to do it, but I can't find any good examples of how to switch tabs. Like in my html, I have inline styles to hide the divs for the tabs that don't show initially.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

**EDIT** this worked for me

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!--
        <input id="test"/>
        <input id="test2"/>
        -->

        <div id="myTabs" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="brand" href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" data-toggle="tab" onclick="document.querySelector('#myTabs li.active').className = '';">Pal</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-02" aria-controls="tab-02" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 01</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-03" aria-controls="tab-03" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 02</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-04" aria-controls="tab-04" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 03</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div id="myTabPanes" class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab-01">A</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-02">B</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-03">C</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-04">D</div>
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-beta1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mvc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works without any additional js. Just use pure bootstrap and this HTML markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 01</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-02" aria-controls="tab-02" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 02</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab-03" aria-controls="tab-03" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 03</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab-01">
    content of tab
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-02">
    content of tab
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab-03">
    content of tab
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but how do I get it do that if I click the `<a class="brand" href="#">Pal</a>` it clicks the first tab, i.e. `tab-01` ?

Comment: I tried `<a class="brand" href="#tab-01" aria-controls="tab-01" data-toggle="tab">Shop Pal</a>`, and it almost works. It switches the tab, but it doesn't visually select the first tab, like it doesn't get indented/highlighted.

Comment: Don't know why active class of tab don't switching. Try to add this code:  
  
    `$('.nav-tabs a').click(function(){  
      $(this).parent().parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');  
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
    });`  
But it's bad practice.

Comment: I got it to work by making a dedicated tab for the brand button, and showing that by default. Then putting `onclick="document.querySelector('#myTabs li.active').className = '';"` on the brand button.

Comment: Some "proper" ways to switch tabs programmatically are listed here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript

Comment: Just giving an example for comment by @AaronDuniganAtLee: Recommended -- and easiest -- way to switch tabs programmatically is to reference the tab element and use Bootstrap's built-in `tab` function: `$('#myTabList a[href="#myTab"]').tab('show')`.